# Fade out Div / Section in vue.js when reaching target section

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

With jQuery this was always simple enough to do but am wondering how to accomplish with Vue.js. I have a sticky element on page and when that reaches a certain div id or class on scroll I want to fade it out and when scrolls back above it fade back in. I have a click event scroll currently functioning as expected on the element but am stuck on the scroll position fade in / out. div class="collapsed" is a fixed bottom element on page. When that scrolls to "fade-in-out" I would like "collapsed" to fade out and when scrolls back up past "fade-in-out" fade back in.

HTML:

```
<transition name="fade">
<div class="collapsed" v-show="show">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>
          lorem ipsum <a href="#" @click.prevent="fadeOut() + handleScrollTo('gloabl-box')"></a>
        </p>
        <div>
          <p>Nullam sollicitudin a sapien sed</p>
          <p>
            Etiam ultricies elit vel sapien convallis, nec volutpat lacus imperdiet.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</transition>
```

OTHER DIV:

```
 <div class="container" id="fade-in-out">
 </div>
```

js:

```
export default {
name: 'app',
data() {
return {
  show: true
};
},
methods: {
fadeOut: function() {
  this.show = false;
}
}
};
```

css:

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concept is no difference. If you can do in jQuery so you can do the same in Vue.js.

```html
<div id='app'>
  <transition name='bottom'>
    <div class='bottom' v-show='show'>
      {{ lorem }}
    </div>
  </transition>
  <div class='target' ref='target'>
    <p>{{ lorem }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    show: true,
    lorem: `Lorem Ipsum...`
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.listener = () => {
      let rect = this.$refs.target.getBoundingClientRect()
      let top = window.innerHeight - rect.top
      this.show = top < 0
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listener)

    /* with Intersection Observer API

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(() => {
      let rect = this.$refs.target.getBoundingClientRect()
      let top = window.innerHeight - rect.top
      this.show = top < 0
    })
    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.target)

    */
  },

  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listener)
    /* this.observer.unobserve(this.$refs.target) */
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```
.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 24px;
  color: white;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  &-enter-active,
  &-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  &-enter,
  &-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.target {
  padding: 24px;
  color: white;
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k26Lsjrg/)

Comment: this works in a single file but my issue is these are two different vue components. Thanks for the info though, gives me some thought and direction

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you please check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776168/hide-navbar-component-when-it-reaches-footer-component-in-vuejs