# Hide Navbar component when it reaches Footer component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have a fixed Navbar at the bottom and I would like to make it fade out when it meets the Footer element.

I followed this answer: [Fade out Div / Section in vue.js when reaching target section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885754/fade-out-div-section-in-vue-js-when-reaching-target-section)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="fade">
      <Navbar :nav-links="navLinks" v-show="show"></Navbar>
    </transition>
    <router-view />
    <Footer ref="footer" :nav-links="navLinks"></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: true,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.listener = () => {
    //   let rect = this.$refs.footer.getBoundingClientRect();
    //   let top = window.innerHeight - rect.top;
    //   this.show = top < 0;
    // };
    // window.addEventListener("scroll", this.listener);

    // with Intersection Observer API

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(() => {
      let rect = this.$refs.footer.getBoundingClientRect()
      let top = window.innerHeight - rect.top
      this.show = top < 0
    })
    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.footer)
  
  },
  destroyed() {
    /* window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listener) */
    this.observer.unobserve(this.$refs.footer);
  },
};
</script>
```

and it doesn't work at all.

`this.listener` method returns `Uncaught TypeError: _this.$refs.footer.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

and

`this.observer` method returns `TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

I have tried wrapping them inside `$nextTick` but I still get the above errors:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    // methods here
  })
  
},
```

What do you think ?

Comment: If you use ref attribute with Vue component, ref will be Vue component not HTML element so you have to use `this.$refs.footer.$el`. See more https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: Omg, it actually worked. Thank you.

I've went over the docs but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You can post your answer and accept it in case others have the same problem as you.

Comment: But it is your answer. All I did was to add `$el` at the end of `this.$refs.footer`.